# installed eclipse Neon with jdk 8u101 and javaFx still missing?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I installed eclipse Neon and jdk 8u101, since jdk 7, javaFx should be included.
But I cant create javaFx projects.
If I go to File->New there is no option for javaFx and also not in others or Projects.
So since I downloaded the latest version of the jdk, how can I implement javaFx ?

Ohh and I have a javafx-src.zip folder. 
Does that mean something?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Creating JavaFX project only gives you some starting code.
You can just create a regular project, and it will work the same.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I had to install the [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) plugin.

Comment: @Tomasz Nocon I tried that. I created a Java Project and started to write my code  but at the moment I want to write `public class getStarted extends Application` eclipse say: " Nope there is no Application." I tried to import the libraries but it wont work. anything is red marked.

Comment: You could also try: Right Click Project -> Build Path -> Add Library... -> Select "JavaFX SDK" from the list.

Comment: @Jorn Vernee thanks, I got e(fx)clipse now and ist work. I thought I dont need this. I tried the "add Library" way but there are no Java Fx SDK . Thank you very much!